# to see all the names of the dataframe in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a huge combined dataset and I want to see all the names in that dataset

```
names(mydataset)
[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 2166 entries ]
```

but I can not see 2166 entries, how to get around with this 
many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hit the maximum number of name printed to the console. You can increase this by changing the max print value like:

```
options(max.print=30000)
```

Or replace 30000 with a larger number

Answer (score 2):

In `RStudio`, you can try this:

```
View(data.frame(names(mydataset)))
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this.

```
install.packages("strvalidator")
library(strvalidator)
colNames(Your_Data_Set, slim = TRUE)
```

the option slim means: logical, TRUE returns column names occurring once, FALSE returns column names occurring multiple times.

to know more [click here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strvalidator/index.html)